# I cant get data out of firebase in javascript

Tags: javascript, json, firebase

im trying to get data out of firebase to be used in a game programmed in JS. The problem is I can never get the data. this is the JSON i'm adding in the editor:

{xcord: 23, ycord: 3543}

This is the JS code im using to try and get the data:

```
fb.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    obj = snapshot.val();
    alert(obj.xcord);
        c1.x = obj.xcord;
        c1.y = obj.ycord;
        stage.update();
});
```

When the alert pops up, all i get is 'undefind'. Anyone know whats wrong?

Comment: Since (as Terry also says) the code snippet you shared looks good, we'll need more information. It's probably fastest if you set up a small reproduction of your problem in a jsfiddle/plunkr/jsbin.

Comment: Okay. Ill do that im a bit

Comment: Okay so I did the dimenstration on jsbin and i get an output now but I cant extract a value from the json! However I can now alert the entire JSON string. OUTPUT IS FOUND HERE: http://jsbin.com/xaxeqalevi/2/       the code looks like this:   var fb = new Firebase("https://thedatabase.firebaseio.com");
    fb.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
            var json = snapshot.val();
 alert(json);

});

Comment: Please edit your question and add the link to the jsbin and the code. Comments are not a good place for those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I `console.log` your data in the jsbin it shows up as:

```
{sfws: "{xcord: 23, ycord: 3543}", update: "{xcord:'3435'}", update2: "{xcord: 23, ycord: 3543}"}
```

Notice those double quotes around the coordinates? Those mean that they're strings, not JSON object.

I guess you store them with something like this:

```
var coords = document.getElementById('editor').value; // read the text from the input
ref.set(coords);
```

Any value you read from an input is going to be a string, even if to the human eye it looks remarkably close to a JavaScript object.

You will need to convert the value from a string to a JavaScript object, which you can easily do with `JSON.parse`. This requires that you enter the object as proper JSON, which means that you'll need to double quote the property names:

```
'{"xcord": 23, "ycord": 3543}'
```

You can then parse this JSON back into objects either before you send the value to Firebase:

```
var text = document.getElementById('editor').value; // read the text from the input
var coords = JSON.parse(text);
ref.set(coords);
```

Or when you retrieve the string from Firebase:

```
fb.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var text = snapshot.val();
    var obj = JSON.parse(text);
    alert(obj.xcord);
    c1.x = obj.xcord;
    c1.y = obj.ycord;
    stage.update();
})
```

### Quick fix (not recommended)

If you can't be bothered to convert the data into proper JSON, you can also use `eval` to get it back into shape. I *highly recommend against this*, since `eval` is not just less picky about the quotes; it will also allow code fragments to be injected into your page. But if you feel like ignoring the recommendation, this is the quick fix:

```
fb.on('child_added', function(snapshot) {
    var text = snapshot.val();
    eval("obj = "+text);
    alert(obj.xcord);
    c1.x = obj.xcord;
    c1.y = obj.ycord;
    stage.update();
})
```

Comment: So I tried the code snippet where it would convert the string to a value when its retrieved but I get errors. Even worse is they don't give me any useful information. this is the error(from jsbin console):   "error"
"Script error. (line 0)"
"error"
"Script error. (line 0)"
"error"
"Script error. (line 0)"

Comment: Oh right... that's because the string is not valid JSON. In JSON the property names are encapsulated in double quotes: `{"xcord": 23, "ycord": 3543}`. I'll update the answer.

Comment: OH great thanks for the help and working through the problem with me! I understand its a dirty fix but since its something i'm trying to make for myself i'm not too worried about it but I will change it to the proper JSON reading function later as i'm just trying to test it with the value editor that it seems to change it like that. I checked  your awesome response/amazing answer! Again, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks good. Because your alert is coming back 'undefined' leads me to believe something else is wrong. Is the path to your firebase correct?

Comment: Yes I beliveso,my URL is along the lines of: https://myfirebase.firebaseio.com (also the alert happens when i edit so i think the URL is right)